# Automating Picker wheel in Android

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I am unable to perform sendkeys operation to automate the pickerwheel. I have tried all possible ways to get the "id" , xpath" of the pickerwheel and passed the value but still it is not working out for me. Need help on this.

Following is my code : pickerWheelHours.get(1).sendKeys("30");` where

```
@AndroidFindBy(id="android:id/numberpicker_input")
    protected List<MobileElement> pickerWheelHours;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you edit your question, put your code and error stack trace.

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: I have edited my question and added the code . the id for the hours , minutes and AM PM is same.